# Trouble creating MySQL query in Symfony containing JOIN and RAND()

Tags: sql, mysql, symfony-1.4

How do I do this:

```
SELECT t.id 
FROM table t 
JOIN (SELECT(FLOOR(max(id) * rand())) AS maxid FROM table) 
AS tt 
ON t.id >= tt.maxid 
LIMIT 1
```

in Symfony? (I know how to do basic stuff, but this is too much.

Answer (score 1):

```
$connection = Doctrine_Manager::getConnection()->getDbh();
```

won't work... Try this:

```
$connection = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection()->getDbh();
```

Then:

```
$stmt = $connection->query('SELECT * FROM some_table');
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$connection = Doctrine_Manager::getConnection()->getDbh(); 
$result = $connection->query('SELECT ...');
```

Comment: Do I put this inside the action, or the model class?

Comment: I would put everything related to database rather into the model than action.

Comment: I've been playing around with this for a while now: it keeps returning an error saying connection not found.. arggh.. How do I do this with regular DQL (creatquery()->etc...)?