# Custom SQL query in Symfony not working

Tags: sql, mysql, symfony1, doctrine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Trouble creating MySQL query in Symfony containing JOIN and RAND()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734841/trouble-creating-mysql-query-in-symfony-containing-join-and-rand)

```
SELECT s.content 
FROM table SdumpPost s
JOIN (SELECT(FLOOR(max(id) * rand())) AS maxid FROM table) 
AS ss 
ON s.id >= ss.maxid 
LIMIT 1
```

entered as:

```
$connection = Doctrine_Manager::connection();
$query = 'SELECT p.content FROM table Post p JOIN (SELECT(FLOOR(max(id) * rand())) AS maxid FROM table) AS pp ON p.id >= pp.maxid LIMIT 1';
$statement = $connection->execute($query);

//retrieve random post
$result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

It's not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
$connection = Doctrine_Manager::getConnection()->getDbh(); 
$result = $connection->query('SELECT ...');
```

Comment: What was wrong with my setup?

Comment: Read carefully how I retrieved the PDO connection handler (you tried to use Doctrine connnection).